# Как парсить excel в словарь с вложенными словарями python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Файл excel выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается прочитать через pandas в список, но там, где пустые столбцы получается значение nan

Как прочитать файл таким образом, чтобы были вложенности.
Читала, что есть вариант как-то сделать через parent-child, но не понимаю как это сделать.
Структура данных должна быть dict.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу.

В итоге на выходе надо получить:

```
test_data = {
    'Выберите город': {
        'МСК': {
            'Округ': {
                "ЗАО": {
                    "Выберите район": {
                        "Зюзино": "Текст1111",
                        "Царицыно": "Текст22222",
                    }
                },
                "СЗАО": {
                    "Выберите район": {
                        "Измайлово": "Текст44444",
                        "Войковский": "Текст55555"
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    'СПб': {
        'Район': {
            "Адмиралтейский": 'texttexttexttexttexttext'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Прочитать то просто: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_excel(...)`. Вопрос у вас в основном то про построение дерева.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)